# Android how to add drawables from external folder during build using gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-notifications

I would like to show weather condition and temperature icon under StatusBar.

I have generated a few thousands of all possible combinations which I will set as small icon of `Notification` `Builder`, because it can work only with drawable res (you have to specify `res id`)

However, I don't want to have all that drawables in my drawable folder to keep it clean.

Also I don't want Android Studio to see that drawables, because it begins lagging.

Is it possible to add these icons from some external storage during build of the app?

**NOTE:**

`main.res.srcDirs +=` option will not help, since AndroidStudio will show them under the drawable folder.

It is fine for me that during development Android Studio will not see `R ids` for corresponding drawables, because I use `Resources.getIdentifier(resurseName, "drawable", appPackageName)` in order to get id.

Comment: "because it can work only with drawable res" -- or, limit your app to Android 7.0+, where you can use an `Icon`. Or, limit this specific feature to Android 7.0+, doing something else for older devices.

Comment: I don't want to limit the feature for some users. It would be great to find workaround for Android 4.4 +

Comment: is there any way how to move the drawables during build (maybe merge of resources)?

Comment: most likely `setSmallIcon(int icon, int level)` will save you a lot of work and resource files

Comment: I can't understand how it will help, since every item in <level-list> should point to drawable, e.g.  `<item android:maxLevel="0" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_wifi_signal_1" />` so I need still put all the resources under drawable directory.

Comment: if you have for example 10 weather conditions (sun, cloudy, more cloudy, rain, snow, storm etc) and 60 temperatures (-20, -19 ... 39, 40) all you need is 10 xmls + 10 pngs + 60 pngs = 80 files - in your solution you need 10 * 60 pngs

Comment: Your solution helped. Could you sum up everything and make an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can save a lot of your work and resource files if you use `Notification.Builder#setSmallIcon(int icon, int level)` method, for example consider the xml resource file:

res/drawable/sun.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_sun"/>
    <item>
        <level-list>
            <item android:maxLevel="0" android:drawable="@drawable/minus20"/>
            ...
            <item android:maxLevel="60" android:drawable="@drawable/plus40"/>
        </level-list>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

now you can call `setSmallIcon(R.drawable.sun, level)` where `level` == 0 means -20 degrees and `level` == 60 means 40 degrees, that way if you have X weather conditions (sun, cloud, rain, snow, storm, etc) and Y temperatures you need X xmls + X pngs + Y pngs = 2*X + Y files, in your solution you need X * Y files